# PHP Preg_replace help needed

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, expression

I am trying to replace some html in php with preg_replace and I don't seem to get the regex fine, because I always screw it up.

Could you please help me with it ?

I have the following:

```
<ol><li>text</li><li>text</li></ol>

<ol><li><ul><li>text</li></ul></li></ol>
```

And I want to insert a `<span></span>` right after `<li>` and place the text in `<p>`. I must note that I don't want the `<li>` inside the `<ul>` to be affected.

Thank you !

Comment: Do not parse HTML with regex.

Comment: Can you give an example of the html you ultimately want to have?

Comment: Thanks, though I managed to do it with jQuery, fortunately :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to write a single regexp to handle this (I think it might be possible to do it with a look-behind type match) it'd be easiest to:

- find each `<ol>` with `preg_match_all()`
- iterate through each `<li>` in the results ensuring that it's not wrapped in a `<ul>`

Comment: Thank you, but finally I managed to do it with jQuery. I'm glad I didn't need to use another library just for that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Comment: Thank you, but finally I managed to do it with jQuery. I'm glad I didn't need to use another library just for that.

Comment: I didn't think you could use client side options. I thought you wanted something server side..

Comment: I wanted whatever worked better. I'm sorry for not specifying that :(

Answer (score 1):

Using a regexp for this is a recipe for bugs.

Parse the html so as to be able to manipulate it as objects. There are plenty of libraries to do so: DOM extension, SimpleXML, phpquery, etc. Then manipulate it as you need.

Comment: Thank you, but finally I managed to do it with jQuery. I'm glad I didn't need to use another library just for that.